# Poltergeist usando FromSqlRaw con EF Core 5

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Tengo que recuperar estos datos de 2 bases de datos diferentes dentro de una misma instancia

[image: sql]

Para lo cual meto esa misma sentencia SQL en mi codigo

```
public int ImportarUTEs()
{
  try
  {
    int registrosAñadidos = 0;

    var registrosSAP = _contextSAP.Licitadores
     .FromSqlRaw(@"select  distinct ot.IDLICITADOR as IdLicitador,
                        l.cardcode as CodigoSAP,
                        ic.cardname as Nombre
                    from ofertantes ot INNER JOIN licitadores l on     ot.idlicitador=l.idlicitador
                     inner join ofertas o on o.codigoanalizada=ot.codigoanalizada
                     inner join Fulcrum.dbo.OCRD ic on l.cardcode=ic.cardcode collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
                    where year(o.fechapres)>=2015 AND   
                        ot.idlicitador in(
                            select IDLICITADOR  from LICITADORES
                            GROUP by IDLICITADOR
                            HAVING  COUNT(*)>1 
                            )
                    order by IdLicitador, CodigoSAP")
                .ToList();
```

Pero cual es mi sorpresa cuando veo el resultado obtenido

[image: momtaje]

Cuando tiene que obtener los 2 registros correspondientes al IdLicitador 2368 veo que me llegan 3 registros donde el [8] repite el valor del [6] y en vez de ser el valor correspondiente al IdLicitador 2881 y CodigoSAP 430FULCRUM le asigna el valor IdLicitador 2368. Pero es que lo mas raro aun es que cuando toca recoger los valores del IdLicitador 3150 resulta que hace lo mismo, el IdLicitador 3150 y Codigo SAP 430FULCRUM el [10 ]lo convierte en IdLicitador 2368 y CodigoSAP 430FULCRUM.

Es decir, por alguna razon que no logro comprender el valor obtenido en el proyecto de EF Core 5 no es el mismo que el obtenido en la instancia de SQL Server y no se me ocurre que poder hacer ante esto

Alguna idea por favor?

Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba en la definición de la primary key en la entidad que recibía los resultados

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LicitadorSAP>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.IdLicitador, c.CodigoSAP });
```

Ahora los recoge como debe

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada mediante un click en el check del costado. Saludos.